# Determine the right cosets of $\langle{(13)}\rangle$ in $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Determine the right cosets of $\langle(13)\rangle$ in $S_3$

Here's my attempt

$H={e, (13)}$
$H(12)={(12)(132)}$
$H(123)={(123)(23)}$

I'm not sure about the last one. According to La Grange's, there should be 3 right cosets.

Comment: You should start by finding $H$, which is not just the set with the single element $(1,3)$, it's the subgroup generated by that element, and is one of the cosets. When you write a product of cycles, multiply it out.  (I think there's typo in the question.)

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you, I fixed it

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I apologize, there was a typo. It refers to modulo but I corrected the  notation

Comment: Thanks. Looks fine, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three cosets are as follows

$H=\{{ I,(13)}\}$

$H(12)=\{{ (12),(132)}\}$

$H(23)=\{{ (23),(123)}\}$.